# Using Mockito "when" with parameters that could contain certain values?

Tags: unit-testing, mockito

I'm new to Mockito and am trying to figure out if this case is possible.

I am trying to mock a class, where there's a method that takes in 3 parameters, and based on whether or not the first parameter contains some substring, I return something different from the Mock.

Could someone help point me towards what I can use? I have been digging around Mockito and haven't had any luck.

Example, I'm trying to do something like this (pseudocode):

```
when(myMock.lookup(anyStringThatContains("abc"), anyString(), anyString())
   .thenReturn(ImmutableList.of(...someItems))

when(myMock.lookup(anyStringThatContains("def"), anyString(), anyString())
   .thenReturn(ImmutableList.of(...otherItems))
```

Additionally: 
What happens if the string that I need to check is contained within the object passed in the parameter? 
ie. What if the first parameter has a field, `line` and that's what needs to be checked instead of having the string at the top level?

Comment: updated again :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [eq() matcher](https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/1.9.5/org/mockito/Matchers.html#eq(T)) to match exact string:

```
when(myMock.lookup(eq("abc"), anyString(), anyString())
   .thenReturn(ImmutableList.of(...someItems))

when(myMock.lookup(eq("def"), anyString(), anyString())
   .thenReturn(ImmutableList.of(...otherItems))
```

If you need to match only some part of a string, you can use [matches()](https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/1.9.5/org/mockito/Matchers.html#matches(java.lang.String)) (passing a regex into it) instead:

```
when(myMock.lookup(matches(".*abc.*"), anyString(), anyString())
   .thenReturn(ImmutableList.of(...someItems))

when(myMock.lookup(matches(".*def.*"), anyString(), anyString())
   .thenReturn(ImmutableList.of(...otherItems))
```

About addition: if your string is stored in a variable, you can simply use string concatenation:

```
String str = "abc";
when(myMock.lookup(matches(".*" + str + ".*"), anyString(), anyString())
   .thenReturn(ImmutableList.of(...someItems))
```

or (if it stored inside a field of an object) - like this:

```
MyObject myObject = new MyObject();
myObject.setLine("abc");
when(myMock.lookup(matches(".*" + myObject.getLine() + ".*"), anyString(), anyString())
   .thenReturn(ImmutableList.of(...someItems))
```